# what is the "Sources for sdk" in the Android sdk?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm just starting with android development and want to know what is de  "Sources for sdk" present in Android sdk manager. It's like documentations or it's the bin files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the source files.

This will also enable your IDE to show you the source code when you want to see it (e.g. while debugging), also it contains the javadoc.

Comment: Hum ok! Thank you!